# Elasticsearch dynamic mapping with geopoint

Tags: elasticsearch

We use Elasticsearch to index schemaless data. The thing is that the majority of the entries that we want to index contain fields like `"longitude"`, `"latitude"`, `"lat"` or `"long"`.

What would be the best way to index that data so the field type allows search with geo distance filter ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I ended up doing it in my application and "put the mapping" into elasticsearch before indexing. Not really want I wanted but still it works. Like proposed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151646/how-to-automatically-map-location-to-geo-point-elasticsearch/16153901#16153901

Answer (score 5):

I know it's been some time since you posted this but in case someone stumbles upon it like I did, here's some ways to do it.

In our case, we needed a dynamic radius so here's the mapping we have:

```
"mappings": {
    "mygeopoints": {
        "properties": {
            "geopoint": {
                "type": "geo_point",
                "lat_lon" : true
            },
            "radius": {
                "type": "long"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Our document is indexed using a SQL query that looks like that:

```sql
SELECT label, (lat || ',' || lon) as geopoint, radius FROM points;
```

We're sending the geopoint as a string that contains both latitude and longitude seperated by a coma.

To now search through the points you can use the [geo_distance filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/geo-distance-filter/):

```
"filter" : {
    "geo_distance" : {
        "geopoint" : [ 5.7, 43.5 ],
        "distance" : "15km"
    }
}
```

On our side though, we needed a dynamic range so we did not find any other solution than using a [script filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/script-filter/).

```
"filter" : {
    "script" : {
        "script" : "!doc['geopoint'].empty && doc['geopoint'].distanceInKm(43.5,5.7) <= doc['radius'].value"
    }
}
```

Comment: The "script" you defined queries for lat/lon within the "radius" inside the document?

Comment: @zengr I'm not sure i understand your question.

Comment: Posted it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23661930/conditional-query-for-geo-location-lookup