# How to automatically map location to geo_point ? Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to know how I can set every fields called `"location"` to be a type `"geo_point"`.

Can I use the default mapping for that? If yes I can't find any examples.

Or should I use dynamic templates ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use the dynamic templates. Here is an example of how to do it when creating an index:

```
 curl -XPOST localhost:9200/test -d '{
"settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1
},
"mappings": {
    "_default_:": {
        "_ttl": true,
        "dynamic_templates": [
            {
                "geo_location": {
                    "mapping": {
                        "type": "geo_point"
                    },
                    "match": "location"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
}'
```

Comment: Where should put this? Thanks

Comment: Adjusted answer to show how it is done when creating an index. It can also be done by the put mapping api

Comment: I'll try it as soon as I can. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if it really works. I mean when I look at the mapping once I've reindexed the data. It says that `"location"` is dynamic and that `"lat"` and `"lon"` are double. Is it normal ?

Comment: Then when I tried a filtred query with geo_distance, it just returns all the data.

Comment: My search query was wrong but it still not working. Btw your JSON is not valid.