# Conditional query for geo location lookup

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a usecase where I have 2 types of locations (i.e. with geo_point type):

1. Location 1: Has a lat/lon with say radius=90 miles (it will vary) and type=outgoing
2. Location 2: Has a lat/lon with no radius and type=incoming

Now, when a query comes in with: lat/lon and radius=20, I expect this to happen:

1. Simple geo lookup: If the input lat/lon is within 20miles of location 2, return location 2.
2. If input lat/lon is within 90 miles of Location 1, return location 1 too in the result. If you notice, I want input radius to be overwritten by the saved radius for a specific type of location.

This is what I have come up with using script:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "filter": {
    "script": {
      "script": "!doc['geopoint'].empty && doc['coverage_type'].value == 'outgoing' ? doc['geopoint'].distanceInMiles(37,-121) <= doc['radius'].value : doc['geopoint'].distanceInMiles(37,-121) <= 20"
    }
  }
}
```

Where "37,-121" is input lat/lon and 20 is the input radius.

What do you think about the query, is this the best way to do it?

Originally posted [this on ES mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elasticsearch/mNZ9CWn88IY), no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems ok to me. An other way which is a bit more verbose would be to explode your script into various ES filters so that ES can optimize your request as much as possible (you would be able to use the specific geo_distance filter for one of your cases).
For instance you could have something like this: (sorry if the json isn't exact, i do not have means to test it right now)

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "filter": {
    "bool": {
        "should": [
            {
                "and": [
                    {
                        "term": {
                            "coverage_type": "outgoing"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "script": {
                          "script": "!doc['geopoint'].empty && doc['geopoint'].distanceInMiles(37,-121) <= doc['radius'].value"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "and": [
                    {
                        "term": {
                            "coverage_type": "incoming"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "geo_distance" : {
                            "geopoint" : [ 37, -121 ],
                            "distance" : "20km"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
  }
}
```

You may have to add some specific filters to manage the fact a geopoint can be missing in your document and how you want to treat this. For instance, you may want to allow one to fetch all the documents without a geopoint in which case you could add a "missing" filter to the "should". I hope that helps.